# Is there a aliases file for sSMTP?

Tags: email, cron, smtp, alias

I installed `sSMTP` for sending emails from command line.
I want to create some alias for `cron jobs`:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/aliases
    # append this line at the end
    myname: root

$ newaliases 
newaliases: Aliases are not used in sSMTP
```

So I cannot use `/etc/aliases` any more.
I noticed that there is a `/etc/ssmtp/revaliases` config file.
What's used for? Is it a `aliases` file for `sSMTP`?

Answer (score 3):

The `revaliases` file is used to determine the From header of emails based on the user sending it. The only aliases which sSMTP supports is a single destination for UIDs less than 1000. [This post](http://raftaman.net/?p=591) suggests setting up aliases with the `mail` command, but I'm not sure if cron uses this or executes `/usr/sbin/sendmail` directly.